# Get ListView of messages in parent app. Error: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String on a null object reference

Tags: android, database, firebase, nullpointerexception

This code motive is to get firebase records and display them in a listview ,   but there occurs exception .

> images shows my firebase database.

[image]

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
List<MessageResults> CallList;
ListView listView;
AdapterMessage adapterMessage;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

CallList = new ArrayList<>();
listView = findViewById(R.id.lv);
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = 
database.getReference("callreciver").child("History").child("Messsages");

myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

MessageResults Results=dataSnapshot.getValue(MessageResults.class);
CallList.add(Results);

adapterMessage=new AdapterMessage(getApplicationContext(),CallList);
listView.setAdapter(adapterMessage);
}




@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unable to display data", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
```

> myadapter class
>     . 
>   [image]

adapter class for adding view . i am getting error in line number 31, attempting to read null object.

Is the error bcz i am trying to get data in a wrong way.or some another  issue?

Comment: Which is line 31? At which line are getting the error?

Comment: /*When i try to set textview */                                                                                                
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view1=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.myview,null);
    
        textView1.setText(messageResults.get(position).time+"\n" +messageResults.get(position).Number+"\n"
                          +messageResults.get(position).date+"\n" +messageResults.get(position).Message);
        return view1;
    }

Comment: There are too many lines. Which in particular?

Comment: in my adapter class when  I use textview.settext() . It gives trying to access null  object.

Comment: Post the logcat here

Comment: @Sam here is the error  -> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.example.aashish.parentshield.MessageResults.time' on a null object reference
        at com.example.aashish.parentshield.AdapterMessage.getView(AdapterMessage.java:30)

Comment: so you are adding all your field like message, number, date, time in yout arraylist "CallList"?

Comment: @Sam yes , but when i try to get size of the list it says 0. do you an error with my query for retreiveing data?

Comment: where is your MessageResult class? show it in code

Comment: Firebase has a `DataSnapshot.getChildren()` that you should be looping over in order to add to the adapter... You can't just use `getValue(MessageResults.class)` from the messages reference... When that cannot be parsed, values will be null... Also, please check if it is null before adding into the list/adapter

Comment: yea, as @cricket_007 said, make a loop and add it to the HashMap list, Make array of data you want. Set adapter to your list if values are not null.

Comment: @Sam there is no Hashmap here